# NSMutablearray addobject , added objects not expected

Tags: objective-c

I've a question about `NSMutablearray` `addobject`, I think it's about object lifecycle. Searched but not got answer.

Here's the code:

```
    NSMutableString *str1 = [[NSMutableString alloc]init] ;
    NSMutableArray *arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init] ;
    for (int i=0 ;i<3 ;i++) {
        str1 =[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(random() % 100) ] ;
        [arr1 addObject:str1] ;
        NSLog(@"arr1 inside loop:%@",arr1) ;
        [str1 setString:@""] ;    }
    NSLog(@"arr1 outside loop:%@",arr1) ;

    NSMutableString *str2 = [[NSMutableString alloc]init] ;
    NSMutableArray *arr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init] ;
    for (int i=0 ;i<3 ;i++) {
        str2 =[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(random() % 100) ] ;
        [arr2 addObject:str2] ;        }
    [str2 setString:@"abc"] ;
    NSLog(@"arr1:%@",arr2) ;
```

I expect that `arr1` & `arr2` both include 3 random number objects.
but the real output is:

```
arr1 inside loop:(
    83
)
arr1 inside loop:(
    "",
    86
)
arr1 inside loop:(
    "",
    "",
    77
)
arr1 outside loop:(
    "",
    "",
    ""
)
arr2:(
    15,
    93,
    abc
)
```

Q1: `Arr1`, why the added objects changed to `""`?
(If the reason is all 3 objects are just 3 pointers and they point to the same object, then I have Q2 --)

Q2: `Arr2`, why the last object of `arr2` is `"abc"` but the others not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1:Arr1, why the added objects changed to ""?

Every time you used `[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(random() % 100) ] ;` you created a new `NSMutableString` object and changed the pointer of `str1` so it would *point* to that new object.

However, when you used `[str1 setString:@""] ;`, you changed `str1`'s object value, so you changed the array object value as well, since `[arr1 addObject:str1] ;` adds the `str1` pointer to the `arr1` array only.

> Q2:Arr2, why the last object of arr2 is "abc" but the others not.

This is your code with `{` and `}` in separated lines:

```
for (int i=0 ;i<3 ;i++) 
{
    str2 =[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(random() % 100) ];
    [arr2 addObject:str2] ;
}
[str2 setString:@"abc"] ;
NSLog(@"arr1:%@",arr2) ;
```

You are creating new objects with `[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(random() % 100) ];` and changing the `str2` pointer, adding its pointer to `arr2` in `[arr2 addObject:str2] ;`.

After the `for`, you use `[str2 setString:@"abc"]`, `str2` is pointing to the last object that you created inside your `for`, which is the last item that you added to the array.

Comment: Thanks, vitormm! You're right! str = [NSMutableString stringwith ...] create a new object, and [str setString ...] just modifies the string value, that's the point! Now I modify the code [set string ...] to str = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@""] , then the output is what I want!

Answer (score 0):

`[str1 setString:@""]` modifies the string you have added to the array. In the first step you have a mutable string with value `"83"` but at the end of the iteration you are rewriting this same mutable string with an empty string `""`.

You can remove the line because you don't use the same instance again, actually, you don't need a mutable string at all:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   NSString *randomString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (random() % 100)] ;
   [arr1 addObject:randomString];
   NSLog(@"arr1 inside loop:%@", arr1);
}
```